# Laravel 5.8 - Uploaded Image not showing on Shared Hosting but Shows on Local Server

Tags: php, laravel

I've deployed my laravel project on my Shared Host, and try some my project features one of them is uploading an image. The image successfully uploaded into my Storage Folder, but when I try to view the image, my console give me 404 on that uploaded image URL like this URL :

```
http://member.gunabraham.com/storage/site/images/Site_Logo_1561217248.png
```

But in my local server, the uploaded image shows correctly on this URL :

```
http://localhost:8000/storage/site/images/Site_Logo_1561217645.png
```

This is my `config/filesystems.php` :

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
    ],

],
```

And my HTML file :

```
<a href="{{url('/home')}}" class="brand-logo amber-text center"><img src="{{asset('storage/site/images/'.$siteinfo->site_logo)}}" alt="" width="70" style="margin-top:15px;margin-bottom:15px;">
```

So what should I do on my laravel project which is deployed on Shared Hosting? Thanks for attention.

Comment: have you execute following command: php artisan storage:link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by change my image source in HTML file from :

```
storage/site/images/
```

to :

```
storage/app/public/site/images/
```

Is this right choice? Or there're another solution to solve this problem?

Comment: If you write an answer to your question then you should mark it as solved. If you're not sure whether it's the right way to go then leave it as a comment or an edit rater than posting it as an answer and questioning whether it's good or not.

Answer (score 0):

You want to try link storage folder.
if /public/storage folder is already exists first go to public folder and delete exising storage folder then run this command 
Are you tryed ?
try this command `php artisan storage:link`
if you don't have command pannel in shere hosting please create one route for run a comand

`Route::get('/command',function(){
    Artisan::call('storage:link');
  });`

Comment: I got an error "symlink() has been disabled for security reasons"

Comment: show me your directory structure.
i think this error for if you remove public from url and all public files in main directiry

Comment: So I deployed my project in a subdomain, my laravel app located inside member folder of public_html like this "public_html/member".

Comment: yah right change your root 

like 
`'public' => [
'driver' => 'local',
'root' => public_path('storage'),
'visibility' => 'public',
],`

Comment: and clear everthing like cache and config and then run the command

Answer (score 0):

Your files are being uploaded in the storage path and not the public path. You have mainly two options here:
 1. Change your file-system to public path.

```
 In your /config/filesystems.php
  'public' => [
  'driver' => 'local',
  'root' => public_path('app/public/'),
  'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
  'visibility' => 'public',
],
```

2. Create a **symlink** and point the storage files via public folder. To do this you can run **php artisan storage:link** in your server console. If you don't have console access to server you can do this using a cron job.

Option 1 is better if you are using shared hosting with no console access.

Comment: You can also create a symlink using route. Check the link to find the  available routes for shared hosting: https://sauravkc.com.np/blog/laravel-in-shared-hosting

Comment: I did the 1st option, but no change.

Comment: after you change the public path, did the upload files go to public folder rather than storage folder?

Comment: ah after I checked the storage folder, the image didn't uploaded inside both of that folders.

Comment: Please check the server log and also check if you have appropriate permissions to upload files in the public folder

Comment: I'm sorry, actually the file successfully uploaded in below folders : "storage/app/public/site/images"

Comment: Your config changes didn't take place. Please use php artisan config:clear

Comment: please check my newest answer, give me your opinion about that.